# select subset of data with labels in specific column balanced in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have about 4M records in a table. Each record in this table is distinct. One of the columns 'labels' has two distinct values L1 and L2. I want to randomly select 100000 records such that 50% of this data has label L1 and the rest has L2.

Eg : If the following table is the mastertable and has about 10 rows

```
s_key  C1    C2    labels
s1     0.2   0.1    L1
s2     0.3   0.3    L1
s3     0.25  0.32   L2
s4     1.4   0.5    L1
s5     2.3   9.0    L1
s6     1.2   0.8    L1
s7     0.8   0.4    L1
s8     2.6   9.5    L2
s9     3.7   7.1    L2
s10    2.7   8.3    L2
```

I want to randomly select 4 records from the above table such that 50 % that is 2 records have labels L1 and 2 records have labels L2 and looks like the following

```
s_key  C1    C2    labels
s1     0.2   0.1    L1
s2     0.3   0.3    L1
s3     0.25  0.32   L2
s10    2.7   8.3    L2
```

How can I do this in Tsql/Sql?
Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by labels order by newid()) as seqnum
      from mastertable t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 50000 ;  -- or 100000 / 2, if you prefer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this:

```
SELECT TOP 50000 *
FROM table
WHERE labels = 'L1'
ORDER BY NEWID() 

UNION ALL

SELECT TOP 50000 *
FROM table
WHERE labels = 'L2' 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```